# angular 5 Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have a jhipster project.  It is running fine in dev mode.  When I try to build in production mode (using the cmd "mvnw -Pprod"), I am getting the error :

> ERROR in
>   src\main\webapp\app\entities\ext-task\ext-task-group-list\ext-task-group-list.component.html(1,457):
>   : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
>   src\main\webapp\app\entities\ext-task\ext-task-group-list\ext-task-group-list.component.html(1,665):
>   : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
>   src\main\webapp\app\entities\ext-task\ext-task-list-template\ext-task-list-template.component.html(1,302):
>   : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
>   src\main\webapp\app\entities\ext-task\ext-task-list-template\ext-task-list-template.component.html(1,505):
>   : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

All the 4 errors point to line 1, which is empty.

In order to find the actual line number, I tried following cmd (found in so).

`yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www`

Got the same error.

How do I find the error line number?  Is there any debug option available in mvnw to display more info?  How to resolve this error?

Comment: The error points to line 1 but with a very large column number 457, so I suspect your whole file is viewed as a single line, maybe you have a problem of end of line encoding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, if you are using tree shaking, ex. with `--aot`, especially at build time, it'll check the functions in your templates.

This error states that in your template `template.component.html`, it calls a function with no arguments, but instead you put one after that, ex. `open(true)`

You should be able to find the source code. It should sit inside `src\main\webapp\app\entities\ext-task\ext-task-group-list\ext-task-group-list.component.html`, search for any function called inside this template.

Comment: thanks, going thru the code with some intuition helped fixing the problem.